# Custom callouts are all showing on the map after annotation added

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I am creating custom MKPinAnnotationView, and after the annotation are added to map view. All of them are displaying on the map. But I don't want that, I only want to open the callout when I click on the pin and then show the callout. Right now my code is like below:

CustomAnnotationView.h

```
@interface CustomAnnotationView : MKPinAnnotationView

@property (nonatomic, strong) AnnotationView *annotationView;

@end
```

CustomAnnotationView.m

```
@implementation CustomAnnotationView

- (instancetype)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.annotationView = (AnnotationView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnnotationView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        [self addSubview:self.annotationView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

MapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [[Client sharedClient] searchWithParamaters:parameters completionBlock:^(NSArray *businesses, NSError *error) {
        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!error) {
            [strongSelf.mapView addAnnotations:businesses];
        }
    }];
}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifer = @"Cell";
    CustomAnnotationView *pin = (CustomAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifer];
    if (pin == nil) {
        pin = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifer];
    }

    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.animatesDrop = YES;

    Place *place = annotation;

    pin.annotationView.businessTitle.text = place.name;
    pin.annotationView.businessDetailLabel.text = place.address;
    [pin.annotationView.ratingImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:place.ratingImageSmallUrl]];

    return pin; 
    }
    return nil;
}
```